# VMware workstation on Ubuntu 22.04. is slower compared to windows 10

Tags: 22.04, vmware, kali

Previously, I was using windows 10 as host for vmwares. Studying for PJPT by TCM. Requires kali, windows server and two windows 10, all in vmware. Usually I run this in windows 10, there is no lag, all is good. Wanted to improve my linux skill. format the laptop and started to use ubuntu as host os. Installed all the vms, this time, kali vm always lags, CPU usage shows full. other vms also closes automatically by itself. I tried adjustin the Cores and RAM but still issue persists. Sometimes, ubuntu lags and auto closes the app.

Comment: You can try VirtualBox. Hopefully your will have better performance experience.

Comment: I have tried virtualbox too. issue persists. I even tried in another laptop